# Create VBScript script detect iexplore

Tags: vbscript

I want to create a VBScript script to detect Internet Explorer opening page and opening new tab in the same window. For example, when I manually open Internet Explorer at www.google.com the VBScript will do:

- detect and open new tab in same window with www.example.com
- but do this only once

I tried with this code:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
    page1 = wshShell.AppActivate("Blank page - Internet Explorer")
    If page1 = True Then
        Set page2 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        page2.Navigate "http://www.example.com", CLng(navOpenInNewTab)
    End If
    WScript.Sleep 500
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you must use the existing Internet Explorer instance instead of creating a new one. Unfortunately the way one might expect to be able to do that (`GetObject(, "InternetExplorer.Application")`) does not work for Internet Explorer COM objects. `AppActivate` also doesn't help here, because it doesn't return a handle to the application object, which you need to invoke its methods.  Instead you need to do it this way:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each wnd In app.Windows
  If InStr(1, wnd.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Set ie = wnd
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

If you want to select an instance that has a particular page opened, you can for instance check the title of that page to make the selection:

```
wnd.Document.Title = "something"
```

or

```
InStr(1, wnd.Document.Title, "something", vbTextCompare) > 0
```

---

Your second problem is that VBScript doesn't recognize the symbolic constant `navOpenInNewTab`. You must either use the numeric value (as defined in the [`BrowserNavConstants`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd565688(v%3dvs.85)) enumeration):

```
ie.Navigate "http://www.example.com", CLng(2048)
```

or define the constant yourself first:

```
Const navOpenInNewTab = &h0800&
ie.Navigate "http://www.example.com", navOpenInNewTab
```

Note that you must use hexadecimal notation with a trailing ampersand here, because the value must be a Long and you must use literals in `Const` definitions. Expressions like calling the function `CLng` are not valid.

---

Alternatively you can open a URL in a new tab by omitting the second parameter of the [`Navigate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752093(v=vs.85)) method entirely and instead providing the value `"_blank"` for the third parameter:

```
ie.Navigate "http://www.example.com", , "_blank"
```

However, I'm not certain that this would always open a new tab in the current window (might depend on the browser's tab settings), so I'd recommend using the second parameter (flags) as described above.